# On a decomposition of a conditional distribution

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I am trying to make some sense out of equation (7) in the recent paper of Peter van Leeuwen: *"Representation errors and retrievals in linear and nonlinear data assimilation"*

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qj.2464/abstract

The argument goes as follows. Suppose $y$ are the observations (taken in a modeled area $i$) that will be assimilated, $x$ denotes the value of the model state and $p(y|x)$ is the PDF of $y$ given that the model state is $x$, i.e., the solution of the data assimilation problem. The observation equation reads

$$y = H(x) + \epsilon$$

where $H$ is the observation operator and $\epsilon$ denotes the representation + measurement errors. $H(x)$ is that part of the model state vector that is related to observations in area $i$.

The author then defines the vector $z = H(x) + \tilde{z}$ in observation space, where $\tilde{z}$ is the high-resolution variation (in area $i$) at the location where observation $y$ was taken. Thus, $z$ is a vector with elements $H(x) + \tilde{z}$, where $H(x)$ is the same for all elements and $\tilde z$ varies from element to element.

Equation (7) then reads:

$$
p(y|x) = \int p(y|x,\tilde{z}) p(\tilde{z}|x) \mathrm{d} \tilde{z} = \int p(y|z) p(\tilde{z}|x) \mathrm{d}\tilde{z} .
$$

How exactly is this equation derived? My probability theory is a bit rusty...

Comment: No way to say without more information on the dependence structure of $(x,\tilde{z},\epsilon)$.

Comment: @Did I don't think the author provides any extra information on $x$, $z$ or $\epsilon$. He only states that equation (7) follows from "standard probability theory"...

Comment: It does not. Sorry.

Comment: The author later states that the same equation (7) holds for $z = (x,\tilde{z})^T$. Here $z$ is the _total high-resolution model variable_, which includes $\tilde z$ as the part not represented by the coarse-resolution model variable $x$.

Comment: The hypotheses that $z=(x,\tilde z)^T$ and that $z=H(x)+\tilde z$ have little in common. If  $z=(x,\tilde z)^T$, the substitution $p(y\mid x,\tilde z)=p(y\mid z)$ becomes trivial.

Comment: @Did What about the first equality $p(y|x)= \int p(y|x,\tilde z)p(\tilde z|x)d \tilde z$?

Comment: @Did I have made some edits to my initial question (after reading again the relevant section from van Leeuwen's paper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler example first to highlight the use of marginal distributions:
\begin{align*}
p(y)=\int p(y,\tilde{z})d\tilde{z}=\int p (y|\tilde{z})p (\tilde{z})d\tilde{z}
\end{align*}
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution

Marginal distributions interact with conditional distributions in the following way:
\begin{align*}
p(y|x)=\int p(y,\tilde{z}|x)d\tilde{z}=\int p (y|\tilde{z},x)p (\tilde{z}|x)d\tilde{z}.
\end{align*}
[Joint probabilities, conditional probabilities with the chain rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142558/joint-probabilities-conditional-probabilities-with-the-chain-rule)

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation!